How to use cookies generated from one command/request into another command/request using python's request module?
How to use cookies generated from one command/request into another command/request using python's request module like we do with curl commands?
Below are the two curl requests in which cookies generated from first command are used in the second curl command and also cookie_jar file is updated with new parameters to be used in later curl commands
# First Curl Command/Request

curl -c cookie_jar --location --request POST 'https://exmaple.com/api/wealth/mobile/auth/login' \
--header 'api-key: qweqwexxc123ewervdssdf' \
--header 'request-id: login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "locale": "en",
    "signinId": "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "password": "xxxxxx",
    "remembered": "false",
    "trueIP": "192.168.0.1"
}'


# Second Curl Command/Request

curl -b cookie_jar  -c cookie_jar --location --request POST 'https://example.com/api/wealth/mobile/mfa/evaluatemfa' \
--header 'api-key: xxeer2345632' \
--header 'request-id: xxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "deviceFingerPrint": {
        "platform": "iOS",
        "language": "en",
        "fingerprintCookie": "QWERASDF-WER4-334e-AQW3456-154780ASDF",
        "platformVersion": "14.3",
        "jailbreak": "false",
        "screenWidthHeight": "375.00",
        "appVersion": "1.56",
        "ipAddress": "192.168.0.56",
        "plugins": "",
        "userAgent": ""
    }
}'



cookies values in cookie_jar file are dynamic values and are absolutely needed for authentication to work.
So how can we save cookies from the first curl command and later use them in the second curl command request using python's requests module?
I have tried with below code

from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
from http.cookiejar import MozillaCookieJar

import requests
import json
import argparse
import time
import os


payload = json.dumps({
    "locale": "en",
    "signinId": "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "password": "xxxxx",
    "remembered": "false",
    "trueIP": "192.168.0.1"
})
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'api-key': 'qweqwexxc123ewervdssdf',
  'request-id': 'login'
}

response = requests.request("POST", f'https://example.com/api/wealth/mobile/auth/login', headers=headers, data=payload)
cookies_jar = response.cookies
print(cookies_jar)
cookies = MozillaCookieJar('cookie_jar')
print(cookies)

headers1 = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'api-key': 'xxeer2345632',
  'request-id': 'xxx'
}



cookies = MozillaCookieJar('cookie_jar')



json_data = {
    'deviceFingerPrint': {
        'platform': 'iOS',
        'language': 'en',
        'fingerprintCookie': 'QWERASDF-WER4-334e-AQW3456-154780ASDF',
        'platformVersion': '14.3',
        'jailbreak': 'false',
        'screenWidthHeight': '375.00',
        'appVersion': '1.56',
        'ipAddress': '192.168.0.56',
        'plugins': '',
        'userAgent': '',
    },
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.cookies = cookies
    response = session.post('https://example.com/api/wealth/mobile/mfa/evaluatemfa', headers=headers1, json=json_data)
    cookies.save(ignore_discard=True, ignore_expires=True)


print(response.text)



Sessions: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects

Script 1: Store Cookies in a Cookie Jar
import requests
from requests.cookies import RequestsCookieJar
import pickle

# URL to send the request
url = "http://example.com/login"
payload = {
    'username': 'your_username',
    'password': 'your_password'
}

# Send a POST request with login data
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Login successful")
    
    # Create a cookie jar and add the response cookies
    cookie_jar = RequestsCookieJar()
    for cookie in response.cookies:
        cookie_jar.set_cookie(cookie)
    
    # Save the cookies to a file
    with open('cookies.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(cookie_jar, f)
else:
    print("Login error")

Script 2: Use Stored Cookies to Make a Request
import requests
import pickle

# URL to send the request with cookies
url = "http://example.com/protected_page"

# Load the cookies from the file
with open('cookies.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    cookie_jar = pickle.load(f)

# Send a GET request using the loaded cookies
response = requests.get(url, cookies=cookie_jar)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Request successful with cookies")
    print(response.text)  # Print the content of the page
else:
    print("Request error")


ChatGPT generated answers are not allowed here
